# Hoare triple: Loop invariant and partial correctness

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Below there is Hoare triple in which variable a is an Array of integers, *len*, *x, i* are integer-valued variables, and *r* is a Boolean-valued variable. I have to provide a **loop invariant** (using **predicate logic**) suitable for proving **partial** correctness and explain in words why it is a **loop invariant** and why it is sufficient to prove **partial** correctness.

{0 ≤ *len* }  
 i = 0;  
r = false;  
**while** (*i* < *len*) {  
 **if**(a[*i*] = x){  
*r* = *true*;  
*i = len;*  
}**else**{  
*i = i* + 1  
}  
}  
{(*r* = *true*) ⇔ (∃ *k* : Z · (0 ≤ *k* ∧ *k* < *len* ∧ *a*[k] = *x* ))}

I tried to use **loop rule** and get the **invariant** I by the third premise:

{I∧¬ b} [] S {Q}

What I did:  
{I∧*i* < *len*}  ⇒ {(*r* = *true*) ⇔ (∃ *k* : Z · (0 ≤ *k* ∧ *k* < *len* ∧ *a*[k] = *x* ))}

I can not go anymore at here, because the postcondition is a **tautology**, I do not know how to find an invariant.

Comment: Hey, maybe try computer science stack exchange.

Comment: Thank you, Sir!

Comment: And the guys on computer science stack exchange will appreciate it if you indent your code properly.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3165737/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/106174/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).